# my records are not displaying

Tags: php, mysql

in my project i try to display data from database and this is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="prac.css">
            <title>PHP Practical</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="main">
            <table class="table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee ID</th>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Employee Contact</th>
                    <th>Employee Salary</th>
                    <th>Employee Phone</th>
                    <th>Employee City</th>
                    <th>Join Date</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                require 'config.php';
                $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp");
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_name']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_contact']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_salary']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_phone']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['emp_city']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['join_date']; ?></td>
                        <td><a href="update.php?emp_id=<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>">Update</a> | <a href="delete.php?emp_id=<?php echo $row['emp_id']; ?>">Delete</a></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

i checked my config.php file and it is working fine and in database i have 6 records but it is not displaying any. i try also run query to database and it is working fine in database but not here. please help me.

Comment: use `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` to display error on page

Comment: try to remove the white spaces `mysql_query `, `while (`. Sometime these are the problems...

Comment: instead of _mysql_fetch_array_ use _mysql_fetch_assoc_

Comment: seems correct, let us see your `config.php`.

Answer (score 1):

```
**Use this**

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM emp") or die(mysql_error());

to display mysql error
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mysql_` extension is deprecated. There is no point in using it.
Switch to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

The issue you are currently facing is not caused because of `mysql_` being deprecated but there's no worth in investigating it. It's not used anymore